# how to type foreign language in vi editor

Tags: centos, vi

I want to type text as

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Aparajita}
\begin{document}
\section*{इनपुट साधने ऑनलाइन वापरून पहा}
आपण निवडलेल्‍या भाषेमध्‍ये टाइप करणे सोपे बनवतात
\end{document}
```

I'm using vi editor version 7.2.411 on CentOS. Can you point me to right documentation to type this text. (I've HTML Entities corresponding to foreign language text)

Comment: what terminal or terminal emulator are you using? if you're using emulator, you can use the input method of client OS to input non-ascii characters.

Comment: I'm using 'putty' version 0.58

Comment: So you're connecting from a Windows machine via putty to a remote CentOS system? Could you give these details in your question please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Putty set your enconding here:

Settings > Window > Translation > Remote character set > UTF-8

And in vi:

```
:set encoding=utf-8
```